# Hover on one element causes other element to change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

so on my site I created a functionality where when I hover on one of the side buttons the image of the tree in the middle changes. You can see the page [here.](http://vistacamisa.greenpeace.org.br/)

The animation is working ok, but now I am trying to make the background image responsive within the div. Thanks to this other [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPEFn/2/), I was able to make the original background image responsive using the following CSS:

```
#arvore { 
background: url('http://vistacamisa.greenpeace.org.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/arvore_011.png'); 
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 0;
padding-top: 92.7%;
}
```

The problem is that this CSS does not apply to the image that shows when I hover on the button, and I've hit a roadblock as to how to make it work. Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated!

I'm using the following jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
$('.arvorehover').hover(function(){
    $('#arvore').css({'background':'url('+ $(this).attr('target') +')'});
},function(){
    $('#arvore').css({'background':''});
});
})(jQuery)
</script>
```

My buttons have a class .arvorehover and the div with the tree image has the id #arvore.

Thanks so much!

Comment: It is easier if you toggle a class.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the hover background in your JavaScript using this:

```
$('#arvore').css({'background':'url('+ $(this).attr('target') +')'});
```

...it adds a style attribute to the tag: `<div id="arvore" style="background:url(....)">`, which overrides your entire CSS `background` declaration, which in turn sets `background-size` to `auto`. You can fix your current code by changing only the `background-image` property:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
  $('.arvorehover').hover(function(){
    $('#arvore').css({'background-image':'url('+ $(this).attr('target') +')'});
  },function(){
    $('#arvore').css({'background-image':''});
  });
})(jQuery)
</script>
```

Alternately you can keep the styling in your CSS by toggling a class in your JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
  $('.arvorehover').hover(function(){
    $('#arvore').addClass('hover');
  },function(){
    $('#arvore').removeClass('hover')
  });
})(jQuery)
</script>
```

And then in your CSS:

```
#arvore.hover {
  background-image: url("some-url");
}
```

Comment: `background-image: "some-url"` is not the correct syntax

Comment: @Popnoodles--nope! Edited.

Comment: adding `background-size: contain!important;` will also do the job.